# Awk Command analyze and explain

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have tried reading some tutorial about awk script, but still have doubt with below scripts:

```
get_value_from_ini()  
{  
    section=$1  
    key_name=$2  
    echo `awk -F '=' '/\['"$section"'\]/{a=1}a==1&&$1~/'"$key_name"'/{gsub(/[[:blank:]]*/,"",$2); print $2}' $cfg_file`
}

db_user=`get_value_from_ini DB DBUSER`
db_passwd=`get_value_from_ini DB DBPASSWD`
```

And input config ini file like:

```
....  
[DB]  
DBUSER=dbuser  
DBPASSWD=dbpasswd  
...
```

As I unserstand, in awk command, the pattern is "[DB]", and field seperator is '=', but it worked correctly and can return correct result, Why ? Could you help me understand it ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although poorly written code you simply read from left to right:

```
-F '='  -- As you have said, set FS to =

'/\'"$section"'\]/{a=1} -- If the line contains the information stored in variable section then set a=1

a==1 && $1~/'"$key_name"'/ -- If 'a' set and first field contains the information stored in variable key_name, execute all between {}

{gsub(/[[:blank:]]*/,"",$2); print $2}' -- If previous step returns true, remove all whitespace from second field and then print it out

$cfg_file -- file to be read
```

Here is an alternative to get rid of all the extra quotes which make it very confusing to read and become possibly error prone:

```
get_value_from_ini()
{
  awk -F '=' -vsection="$1" -vkey_name="$2" '$0 ~ "["section"]"{a=1}a==1 && $1 ~ key_name{gsub(/[[:blank:]]*/,"",$2); print $2}' $cfg_file`
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you helped me understand:  
'/\['"$section"'\]/{a=1}a==1    
this is main point I didn't understand  
So, here   '/\['"$section"'\]/{a=1}   is abbreviation of   '$0 ~ "["section"]"{a=1},   could you show me any document contain description abbreviation like this ?

One more thing:
'$0 ~ "["section"]"{a=1}a==1
As I understand we have 3 commands here, right ? we can write like this without separate character ? (I mean ';')

Comment: The curly braces can also be used as a delimiter like ;.  The main documentation is all I normally use :- http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html